# Getting users location and passing it into an Async/Await function before fetching the url

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, scope

I am getting the users weather data based on there location (longitude, latitude).

I'm having trouble passing in the values for longitude and latitude into my fetched url.

How can I pass my longitude and latitude value inside the getWeather() function before the url is fetched?

```
function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  let longitude = crd.longitude;
  let latitude = crd.latitude;
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

async function getWeather() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}

async function showWeather() {
    const weather = await getWeather();
    if (weather) {
        tempContainer.innerHTML = `${Math.round(weather.main.temp)}&deg;C`;
        tempLocationContainer.innerHTML = weather.name;
    }
}

showWeather();
```

Comment: you need to wait for `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to call `success` before calling `showWeather` - suggest you call `showWeather` inside `success`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I did that and passed long, lat as arguments, works now :)

Answer (score 0):

you are creating variables with `let` that restrict the variable to the scope that it is created.

Try to create longitude and latitude outside of the scope of the function, to be accessed globally.

You can also move
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);`
to inside getWeather function.

```js
async function getWeather() {
  let data;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(({latitude, longitude}) => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`);
    data = await res.json();
  }, error, options);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately await cannot be used inside of the navigator.geolocation function because it doesn't use async.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I called the showWeather() function inside the success() function and passed the long and lat as arguments. I then carried those through to my getWeather() function.

I planted many console.logs along the way to track the call stack of each function body.

```
function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;
  const long = crd.longitude;
  const lat = crd.latitude;

  showWeather(long,lat);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

async function getWeather(long, lat) {
    const res = await fetch(`https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}

async function showWeather(long, lat) {
    const weather = await getWeather(long, lat);
    if (weather) {
        tempContainer.innerHTML = `${Math.round(weather.main.temp)}&deg;C`;
        tempLocationContainer.innerHTML = weather.name;
    }
};
```